# is finding danger zones in a map considered as clustering problem?

Tags: clustering, k-means, unsupervised-learning

if I have a data-set of places where accidents happened in certain city , is identifing danger zones in that city considered as clustering problem ?

if for example I use KMeans , I would have to pass the n_clusters which I don't really know. I can't find the way to approach this.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `identifing danger zones in that city`?

Comment: @ttnphns given coordinates (data points) of places where accidents occured , I want to find which zones are high likely to be danger (probablity of having an accident in that zone is high)  than others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Density based clustering can indeed be seen as "identifying areas with high accident density".

K-means is a poor choice, as it will always include even low density points in clusters. Don't use it for problems like this.

Yes, I'd rather use a classic **density estimation**. Much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, but probably not. Clustering is usually about how observations go together based on how similar they are on certain variables. But 1) It is unsupervised learning - you don't tell the program what to look for. In your case, you do know what you want to find.  2) You have to impose geographical structure somehow.

I would look into two dimensional smoothing methods based on the number of accidents (probably scaled by population) in a given neighborhood.